using ROS 2 with Python 3.10 on Windows
I'm currently trying to use ROS 2 with Python 3.10 on Windows. Unfortunately I cannot downgrade to 3.8 because one of the packages I'm going to use requires 3.10.
I created a virtual Conda environment and created a shortcut
C:\Python38

to link to the virtual environment directory under C:\Users\Administrator\.conda\envs\ros2.
However, while attempting to run the example node I'm running into the error:
(ros2) C:\>ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
failed to create process.

Is there any workaround for me to use ROS2 with Python 3.10?
Also, I'm currently not considering Robostack because it requires both Conda and Mamba, and from what I've seen online, it's not recommended that I install both at the same time.
